# Java Compiler API to get tokens?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

Is there some part of the JavaCompiler, or Java ToolProvider that would allow me to get a list of all the tokens in a Java file?  That is, all the legal tokens (each as a data structure preferably), and put them in a list (or other data structure)?  I know there's probably a 3rd party api out there somewhere, but I'm wondering if it can be done via the javax.tools library, or another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the Abstract Syntax Tree of Java compilation units from the [Eclipse JDT API](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/). With a little bit of effort this can also be used as standalone. You may use the [AST view](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) as an example.

Comment: Thanks SpaceTrucker.  I may end up having to go with a 3rd party api.  Do you know of anyway to obtain an AST through the normal system library?

Comment: @Matt8541 no, I don't know, but I'm also not keen on that API.